# Why does clean compile "test-app -unit -integration" run tests twice?

Tags: grails, jenkins

In Jenkins job, my grails target does:

```
clean compile "test-app -unit -integration"
```

And it outputs the tests results twice.

I check `.jenkins/jobs/myjob/target/test-reports`

and there are XML corresponding to the tests but there is no duplication. So everything look likes it only executes once. Same with the console log - I can only see the test execute once.

However, when I look at the build results on Jenkins all the tests are duplicated.

I go to:

```
.jenkins/myjob/builds/buildnumber/junitResult.xml
```

and I can see the tests duplciated in this.

So it is as if when Jenkins creates the `junitResult.xml` file it copies tests.

Any ideas why?

Comment: console output, please.

Comment: @amisuno I having having difficulty putting that up. SO won't let me.  So I have updated description with further info.